# (Python Selenium) Automatically Close Webdriver When Closing Browser

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

In my current script, I specifically tell Selenium to not close the session/process/page using this line of code `Options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)` because I want to interact with the webpage until I'm done with it. However, this method seems to leave Webdriver/ Chromedriver hanging when I close the browser (Chrome) (meaning: not properly ended). Is there a way for me to automatically kill all the process related to Webdriver every time I close my browser?

Comment: You want to kill `chromedriver.exe`?  For example, `taskkill /im chromedriver.exe /f'` or `killall chromedriver` on Win and Linux, respectively?